# Xcode 15 - Live Issues not appearing until I build solution

Tags: xcode

I recently updated to Xcode 15.0.  When I type in some intentionally bad code, Xcode is not highlighting the issues until I build the solution.  I'm only using Objective C.

NOTE: I may have skipped over some of the 14 versions (or skipped 14 entirely?).  I remember a while back selecting to build using the legacy build system which was deprecated and now no longer an option.  I also had to update my "User Header Search Paths" after updating to 15.0 because when I tried to import files in different folders in my project, they wouldn't appear as suggestions by xcode (but it wouldn't be an error either after compiling). Not sure if any of that is a clue to this problem.

Before compiling:
[image]

After compiling:
[image]

Things I've attempted to do:

- Delete Xcode derived data
- Clean build folder
- Update macOS to Sonoma 14.0
- Turn on/off (multiple times, restarting Xcode each time) Xcode -> Settings -> General -> "Show live issues"
- Restart Xcode multiple times and laptop too

Comment: I am facing this as well. Looking out for solution. Seems to be an Xcode bug clearly.

Comment: I am looing for the fix too. I am working on Flutter

Comment: Has anyone found any solution? I'm also facing the same..